# Not getting output when using docker internal IP address

Tags: docker, containers, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using docker container for my asp.net core web api application and container is up and running.

Now I am getting docker internal IP address using below command,

`docker inspect -f "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" d986472784cb` and getting the IP address as `172.20.0.2`.

Now I am not getting any result when hitting below url in browser

`http://172.20.0.2/WeatherForecast`, seeing `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error.

local address `https://localhost:32772/weatherforecast` is just working fine.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container-private IP simply doesn't work in a variety of common circumstances:

- If you're not calling from the same host, the container-private IP won't be reachable at all
- If there is a VM involved at all (Docker Toolbox on Windows, Docker Desktop on Windows or Mac), the container-private IP won't be reachable at all
- If you're not on the same Docker-internal network, you might not be able to reach the container-private IP

Since it doesn't work in so many environments, I wouldn't recommend looking up this IP address at all: forget that particular `docker inspect` command exists.  From the browser, use your host's IP address or DNS name (or `localhost` if the containers and browser are on the same system, but not if Docker Toolbox is involved) and the published port number (`docker run -p` option, Docker Compose `ports:` option, the first port number from that pair).

Comment: Thanks. I have 2 web app running in same container network `WebApi` and `WebFront`. I saw somewhere it automatically resolved DNS, but even `http://webapi/weatherforecast` is also not accessible. Question, Is this necessary that we must have to use port number?

Comment: You don't generally need a port number when it's the default port number for its protocol (80 for unencrypted HTTP, 443 for HTTP/TLS, 5432 for PostgreSQL, 6379 for Redis, ...).  Otherwise, the port number is required.  (Not Docker-specific.)

Answer (score 0):

You need the port number in the ip address url. http://172.20.0.2:32772/WeatherForecast